# If we say "classes of non-zero integers modulo $n$", why does this not include the $0$ class?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I suppose this is a bit of a wording question more than anything else - I'm working through group theory and was learning that "the (classes of) non-zero integers modulo $p$ form an Abelian group under multiplication." It's the wording of this that gets me a bit confused. Let's say $p = 3$. From my understanding the group described is meant to contain $\{[1],[2]\}$. I completely get why this would be an Abelian group under multiplication. However, if we're looking at all the non-zero integers modulo $3$, it seems to me like the "non-zero" attribute binds to the integer part only. So it's $\mathbb{Z} - \{0\}$ (which would include $3,-3,6,-6,...$) modulo $3$. Hence, since integer multiples of 3 are included in this set, $[0]$ would also be included. But clearly my interpretation can't be the case since including $[0]$ would mean it's not a multiplicative group.

In summary, it's like I'm having trouble with the order of operations here:

Interpretation 1: (set of non-zero integers) modulo $p$

Interpretation 2: set of non-zero (integers modulo $p$)

So am I supposed to interpret it like interpretation 2? Since it seems like interpretation 1 would include $[0]$.

Comment: Yes, this is just a bit of sloppy wording. The intent is clearly "the set of equivalence classes modulo $p$ that do not contain zero."

Comment: If you are going to argue language and syntax then you must consider what role exactly do "modulo n" serve in the phrase ""the (classes of) non-zero integers modulo n"  It can't be an adjective because in is after the noun.  It could refer to the classes modulo n but then how exactly was the "non-zero integers" cobbled in where it doesn't fit.  To my mind an "[integer modulo n]" is a phrase we are suppose to recognize as a modulo class and so a "non-zero [integer modulo n]" is clearly a non-zero modulo class; of which there are two.  Admittedly this makes the "class of integers" redundant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the "blocking" isn't and shouldn't be "[non-zero integers] [modulo $p$]" but rather "[non-zero][integers modulo $p$]"

You have three [integers modulo $3$].  They are $[53], [-216]$ and $[3{,}691]$.  $[53]$ and $[3{,}691]$ are non-zero [integers modulo $3$].  And $[-216]$ is not a non-zero [integer modulo $3$].

Comment: What does it mean when you write two integers into the brackets?

Comment: @celtschk The comma supposedly is the thousends delimiter

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Thank you.

Comment: I would be fine with this interpretation, if the original formulation din't have the unfortunate "classes of" in the beginning

Comment: Thank you @fleablood. Just to make sure I understand, the example you gave is for a fixed $p = 3$, as I gave in the original comment, right?

Comment: Well don't take anything I say TOO literally.  I'm mostly talking language usage rather than anything technical.  Yes, I did mean p = 3 (I'll edit that).  And yes I meant thousands delimiter.  And, yes, "classes of" bugs me too.  But I take this as the lesser of evils and... it's only language, no math (the math meaning is obvious in context).  Also that the "classes of" was in parenthesis I presume the actual text was something slightly (possibly relevantly) different.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen What's the difference between \$[3,691]\$ ($3,691$ ) and \$[3{,}691]\$ ($[3{,}691]$).  Also, what is the european standard for thousand deliminations?  It's an empty space?  Right?  ($[3\ 691]$)?

Comment: Oh, I see.  A comma defaultly adds a space and the brackets don't.  I guess that does subtly change things.  It's barely noticeable but I guess it does make a difference.

Comment: @fleablood: Well, it was noticeable enough that it did affect the parser in my brain. As of the “European standard”: I don't think there's such a thing; it's done differently in different countries. But that was not the reason it threw me off; in Germany the comma (without space afterwards) has the same function as the point in English numbers, so if I had misinterpreted it as that, I wouldn't have asked about two integers, but about a single non-integer. The small space (`\,` in $\rm\LaTeX$/MathJax) is the least ambiguous option for a thousands separator, though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, interpretation 2 is the only one that makes sense. Why else would the term "non-zero" even be there?

An alternative phrasing with less ambiguity would be "non-zero classes of integers modulo $n$".

Comment: But that alternative is awkward. Nobody talks like that. The OP should recognize that interpretation 1 is essentially useless, so the OP has to get over the idea that anyone would ever care about interpretation 1.  Many times in math there is an abuse of language, and this is one of those times.

Comment: @KCd I must admit that I would have talked like that ...

Comment: @KCd you're right - I didn't ask this to be pedantic in any way, but rather, since these elementary concepts are so fundamental to my understanding of abstract algebra, I want to make sure that I myself am interpreting everything correctly, and that rather than me misunderstanding I wanted to get confirmation that there is a bit of language abuse going on here.

Comment: I'd say "non-zero classes of integers modulo n".  After all it is the *classes* not the integers that are non-zero (hence the entire reason for the OP).  The only other option would be "classes of integers modulo n not congruent to zero" which is unnescessarily not.   I suppose I'd actually so "non-zero classes modulo n" and assume the integers is implied.